# yield unexpected expression syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a dictionary using yield, assigning a value to it seems to cause some kind of an error. My value for yield is a variable `title` which contains `title = response.html("h1").extract()`

```
import scrapy


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Quotes"
    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.html("h1").extract()
        yield (' titletext ' : title)
```

I've tried replacing `yield` with `return` but that fails to extract the HTML. When I run the code, I get the error.  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in `yield (' titletext ' : title)` What is the correct syntax for yield?

Without the error, I hope to be able to extract the h1 element from this website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
yield { 'titletext': title }
```

The colon `:` means that it's a key-value pair, and that needs to go inside a dictionary, which is delimited by `{}` not `()`.